# How to Create a jQuery New Message Popup Dialog

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, popup

I am trying to create a jQuery powered popup block which users can compose a new message. I can most likely figure out the HTML/CSS to design and scale it... but does anybody have a solution for actually creating the popup?

Below is a Dribbble shot which is very close to what I'm trying to create:

[image: Dribbble Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery UI's Dialog widget. Here's a [link to an example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) with a form in the dialog.

With that, you simply create your content in a `div`, give that `div` and `id`, and use `$("#divId").dialog();`

The `dialog` function takes a large number of properties that you can use to control it's behaviour, such as `autoOpen`, to control whether the dialog opens automatically on page load, `width` and `height`.

Comment: hey man thanks so much. just found your answer here it's perfect. I'm digging through jQuery docs on dialog() right now